# How to stream Twitter API in spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, data-science-experience

How to read Twitter tweets using scala using spark streaming.
I am not able to find any spark connectors for Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

I used `spark-streaming-twitter` twitter connector to read the tweets.
To install this on DSX, I used `pixiedust`.

spark-streaming-twitter

```
import pixiedust

pixiedust.installPackage("org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.0.1")

import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._

TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
```